# COM port event handler fails if polled

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a little gun shy about asking questions as they have been voted down, but this was is driving me crazy.  I can see from all of the Serial port event handler questions that this is a popular subject.  After much effort, I got the following code working:

```
   public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE) {
        try {
            rdata = (byte) comIn.read();
            line_buffer[line_ptr++] = rdata; 
            data_available = true;
//              System.out.print((byte)rdata);
            if( rdata == '\n') {
                line_available = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print("Failed to read data. (" + e.toString() );
        }
    }
}
```

I say that it is working because if I uncomment the print, I see the data that I am expecting.  I have also set breakpoints on the lines that set the data_available and the line available flags and they occur.

I am trying to communicate with this code with the following:

```
// Code that requests data to be send back

// Code that inserts a delay for data to be received

    while( comm.line_avaiable() == false ) { } 

    for(int j=0;j< comm.line_ptr; j++) {
      System.out.print( (char)comm.line_buffer[j] );
}
```

This code is to wait for data_available and then print the line of data received. With the code as shown, the while loop never gets data_available.  Not only that, the event handler does not get any events.  No data is echoed (with comment removed) and a break point is never hit.

IF i comment out the while loop that waits for data_available (and add the delays for the data to be received since we are running without a handshake, the data is received just fine.  The event handler does hit break points if set and can echo data.

How can polling the line_available flag break the event handler?

Comment: This is so confusing. I think you're mixing `line_available` and `data_available`

Comment: I have both flags.  The above example uses the equivalent of a read line.  Elsewhere I get back a single byte response and will use data available.

Comment: `while( comm.line_avaiable() == false ) { }` do you really want your CPU spinning at 100% utilization while it waits for data to be available?  I assume `serialEvent()` is being invoked by on an event-handling thread... you should use semaphores, or at least wait/notify to have your consumer pause until a line is available.

Comment: Please elaborate ...  The serialEvent comes from a COM port. Not really, but the driver makes the USB port look like an COM port. The data_available is what I think of as a semaphore.  It does not seem to matter if I read the public variable directly or use the method above which just returns the boolean.  What should I be doing to prevent high speed spinning?

Comment: I have not worked with comm ports, but based on a cursory examination of the docs, you should be able to wrap `CommPort#getInputStream()` in an `InputStreamReader` and then wrap that in a `BufferedReader` to have the I/O system handle everything for you. `BufferedReader` provides a `readLine()` method, and you shouldn't need to handle events directly.

Comment: I chased that for a while as my goal was was readln which required the buffered reader.  After having gone through finding ports, connecting to one of them, connecting them to input and output streams, initiating a listener, you still have to provide the event handler with the input stream.  The examples for RXTX don't talk about how to get data from there into the Input Stream for the Input Stream Reader.